# Go - regex inside loop

Tags: regex, go

I have a file with a list of 600 regex patterns that most be performed in order to find a specific id for a website.

Example:

```
regex/www\.effectiveperformanceformat\.com/5
regex/bam-cell\.nr-data\.net/5
regex/advgoogle\.com/5
regex/googleapi\.club/5
regex/doubleclickbygoogle\.com/5
regex/googlerank\.info/5
regex/google-pr7\.de/5
regex/usemarketings\.com/5
regex/google-rank\.org/5
regex/googleanalytcs\.com/5
regex/xml\.trafficmoose\.com/5
regex/265\.com/5
regex/app-measurement\.com/5
regex/loftsbaacad\.com/5
regex/toldmeflex\.com/5
regex/r\.baresi\.xyz/5
regex/molodgytot\.biz/5
regex/ec\.walkme\.com/5
regex/px\.ads\.linkedin\.com/5
regex/hinisanex\.biz/5
regex/buysellads\.com/5
regex/buysellads\.net/5
regex/servedby-buysellads\.com/5
regex/carbonads\.(net|com)/5
regex/oulddev\.biz/5
regex/click\.hoolig\.app/5
regex/engine\.blacraft\.com/5
regex/mc\.yandex\.ru/5
regex/ads\.gaming1\.com/5
regex/adform\.net/5
regex/luzulabeguile\.com/5
regex/ficanportio\.biz/5
regex/hidelen\.com/5
regex/earchmess\.fun/5
regex/acrvclk\.com/5
regex/track\.wg-aff\.com/5
regex/thumb\.tapecontent\.net/5
regex/betgorebysson\.club/5
regex/in-page-push\.com/5
regex/itphanpytor\.club/5
regex/mktoresp\.com/5
regex/xid\.i-mobile\.co\.jp/5
regex/ads\.tremorhub\.com/5
```

So far what i'm using is something like this

```
for _, line := range file {
l := line
data := strings.Split(l, "/")
if data[0] == "regex" {
                match, _ := regexp.MatchString(``+data[1]+``, website)
                if match {
                    id, _ = strconv.Atoi(data[2])
                }
            }
}
```

This is working, but i wonder if there is a more optimized way to do this.
Because, if the website match with the regex on the top, great, but if not, i need to intenered the loop over and over till find it.

Anyone can help me to improve this?

Best regards

Comment: Is this code executed once in the application, or is it called multiple time with different values of website?

Comment: Is there a specific performance concern that you’ve measured and have an incentive to address? One thing that caught my eye is that all of the regexes you included (with the exception of ‘carbonads\.(net|com)’) are really just string literals. Seems like you could make do with something like strings.Contains(url, host). How many websites are you matching at a time?

Comment: I wonder if you combine all of the regexp into a single OR expression `|` whether you can execute them all in a single pas.

Comment: @CeriseLimón i'm invoking multiple times, every time that on client access to the API, this invokes the function.

Comment: @ZachYoung I have around 600 regex patterns with diferent IDs

Comment: @icio I have around 600 regex patterns with diferent IDs, so i don't think that i can combine all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to reduce the time you can cache the regexp.

```golang
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    csvutils "github.com/alessiosavi/GoGPUtils/csv"
    "log"
    "os"
    "regexp"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    now := time.Now()
    Precomputed("www.google.it")
    fmt.Println(time.Since(now))
    now = time.Now()
    NonPrecomputed("www.google.it")
    fmt.Println(time.Since(now))
}
func NonPrecomputed(website string) int {
    for _, line := range cachedLines {
        l := line
        data := strings.Split(l, "/")
        if data[0] == "regex" {
            match, _ := regexp.MatchString(``+data[1]+``, website)
            if match {
                id, _ := strconv.Atoi(data[2])
                return id
            }
        }
    }

    return -1
}
func Precomputed(site string) int {
    for regex, id := range rawRegex {
        if ok := regex.MatchString(site); ok {
            return id
        }
    }
    return -1
}

var rawRegex map[*regexp.Regexp]int = make(map[*regexp.Regexp]int)
var cachedLines []string
var sites []string

func init() {
    now := time.Now()
    file, err := os.ReadFile("regex.txt")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(bytes.NewReader(file))

    for scanner.Scan() {
        txt := scanner.Text()
        cachedLines = append(cachedLines, txt)
        split := strings.Split(txt, "/")
        if len(split) == 3 {
            compile, err := regexp.Compile(split[1])
            if err != nil {
                panic(err)
            }
            if rawRegex[compile], err = strconv.Atoi(split[2]); err != nil {
                panic(err)
            }
        }
    }
    file, err = os.ReadFile("top500Domains.csv")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    _, csvData, err := csvutils.ReadCSV(file, ',')
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    for _, line := range csvData {
        sites = append(sites, line[1])
    }
    log.Println("Init took:", time.Since(now))
}
```

The `init` method take care of regexp cache. It will load all the regexp in a map with the relative index (it will load the test data too just for the benchmark).

Then you have 2 method:

- `Precomputed`: use the map of cached regexp
- `NonPrecomputed`: the copy->paste of your snippet

As you can see where the `NonPrecomputed` method is able to perform 63 execution, the `Precomputed` is able to perform 10000 execution.
As you can see the `NonPrecomputed` method allocate ~67 MB when the `Precomputed` method have no allocation (due to the initial cache)

```
C:\opt\SP\Workspace\Go\Temp>go test -bench=. -benchmem -benchtime=10s
2022/11/03 00:45:35 Init took: 10.8397ms
goos: windows
goarch: amd64
pkg: Temp
cpu: 11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1185G7 @ 3.00GHz
Benchmark_Precomputed-8            10000           1113887 ns/op               0 B/op          0 allocs/op
Benchmark_NonPrecomputed-8            63         298434740 ns/op        65782238 B/op     484595 allocs/op
PASS
ok      Temp    41.548s
```

Comment: Hi, many thanks for you quick reply, sorry this question but i'm newby on go. In you example the Precomputed will be the better option right? can be addaped to my regex file?

Comment: also, in your example  csvutils.ReadCSV is used for what?

Comment: The code can be copy and pasted into your module, is already adapted to your file (`regex.txt`). The `csvutils.ReadCSV` is used in order to read the csv file used for test (it contains 500 site). You need the `init()` method code until the first `for` loop (`for scanner.Scan() {`) and the `precomputed` method in order to initialize the regex.

Comment: Hi, you solution works like a charm, many many thanks.
I just have one more doubt, what the diference between run it on init() over run it on main() ?

Comment: https://golangdocs.com/init-function-in-golang. It's a method delegated to perform initialization. It's runned automatically before the main function.